The created FileHandler does not appear in OneDrive and SharePoint
I tried to develop a file handler for my OneDrive and SharePoint environment. I followed the document below :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/file-handlers/?view=odsp-graph-online
Despite completing all the necessary steps and waiting for a certain period, I cannot see the custom button I created in my OneDrive. Here are the steps I took:

I created a new application from the app registration section in Azure.
I granted the necessary permissions on the API Permission side (Files.ReadWrite.All, openid, Directory.AccessAsUser.All).
I added the following field to the manifest:



    "addIns": [
        {
            "id": "7f3fb52d-8c9b-43c9-a754-1bb9358bacd1",
            "type": "FileHandler",
            "properties": [
                {
                    "key": "version",
                    "value": "2"
                },
                {
                    "key": "fileTypeDisplayName",
                    "value": "Test Contoso Markdown"
                },
                {
                    "key": "fileTypeIcon",
                    "value": "{\"svg\":\"https://uxwing.com/wp-content/themes/uxwing/download/education-school/exam-test-icon.svg\",\"png1x\":\"https://uxwing.com/wp-content/themes/uxwing/download/education-school/exam-test-icon.png\",\"png1.5x\":\"https://uxwing.com/wp-content/themes/uxwing/download/education-school/exam-test-icon.png\",\"png2x\":\"https://uxwing.com/wp-content/themes/uxwing/download/education-school/exam-test-icon.png\"}"
                },
                {
                    "key": "appIcon",
                    "value": "{\"svg\":\"https://uxwing.com/wp-content/themes/uxwing/download/education-school/exam-test-icon.svg\",\"png1x\":\"https://uxwing.com/wp-content/themes/uxwing/download/education-school/exam-test-icon.png\",\"png1.5x\":\"https://uxwing.com/wp-content/themes/uxwing/download/education-school/exam-test-icon.png\",\"png2x\":\"https://uxwing.com/wp-content/themes/uxwing/download/education-school/exam-test-icon.png\"}"
                },
                {
                    "key": "actionMenuDisplayName",
                    "value": "Test Contoso Actions"
                },
                {
                    "key": "actions",
                    "value": "[{\"type\":\"newFile\",\"url\":\"https://www.google.com\",\"availableOn\":{\"file\":{\"extensions\":[\".md\"]},\"web\":{}}},{\"type\":\"open\",\"url\":\"https://www.google.com\",\"availableOn\":{\"file\":{\"extensions\":[\".md\"]},\"web\":{}}},{\"type\":\"preview\",\"url\":\"https://www.google.com\",\"availableOn\":{\"file\":{\"extensions\":[\".md\"]},\"web\":{}}}]"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]



I followed all the steps described in the repository below:

https://github.com/pnp/contoso/tree/main/filehandler

I tried the cache clearing steps described at the following URL:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/file-handlers/reset-cache?view=odsp-graph-online
Despite all these steps, I do not see any custom button for any .md file in my OneDrive.
What might I be missing?
